# Python: function menu not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, menu

I am having trouble with a menu that allows the user to choose which function to call. Part of the problem is that when I run the program it starts from the beginning (instead of calling the menu function), and the other part is that I don't know how to pass the table and the number of rows and columns from the first function to the rest of them (when I tried it said they were not defined). The program is supposed to encrypt and decrypt text using a table.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a main function to run what you are doing.
That main function will hold the variables for your table, nc, and nr.
In the main function:

- make a variable called at_menu.  Set it to true.

- create a "while( at_menu ):" loop that will always return to the menu.

- in the while loop put your code to solicit the option.

- have separate if/elif/else statement to catch the options.

- the returns from you table(), encrypt(), and decrypt() will then reassign the variable values in your main function.

Something like this:

```
def get_option()
    #code to request option, validate it is valid
    return option

def table():
    # Your table code
    return tb, nc, nr

def encrypt( tb, nc, nr ):
    # your code

def decrypt( tb, nc, nr ):
    # your code

def main():
    option = None
    at_menu = true
    table = None
    nc = None
    nr = None
    while( at_menu ):
        option = get_option()
        if option == 1:
            ret_tup = table()
            table = ret_tup[0]
            nc = ret_tup[1]
            nr = ret_tup[2] # magic numbers bad
        elif option == 2:
            # should add code to confirm table is not None.
            encrypt( table, nc, nr )
        elif option == 3:
            # should add code to confirm table is not None and it has been encrypted
            decrypt( table, nc, nr )
        elif option == 4:
            at_menu = false
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't scroll all the way down and missed your main function and you menu function.  But it still holds up.  Menu doesn't actually return the value.  So there is no navigation.  Then the actual table, encrypt, and decrypt functions return values that aren't being caught so they can't be used again in later functions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass a variable from a function to another it needs to be ‘‘global’’. One easy way to do that is to initialize the variable outside of all functions and just let all functions call it. This way it will be defined in all functions.

Comment: Is there another way? I've heard global variables should be avoided for some reason.

Comment: Global variable should be avoided for 2 reasons: 1, they might conflict with a variable of the same name from a library you’re importing. And 2. you may forget and try to use the same name again. But either way you really shouldn’t worry about it. Global variables are definitely the way to go. The other way would be to define a new class and store the values in an instance of that class. But that seems like too much trouble for such an easy thing.

Comment: Seeing ass how impractical that is I’m gonna politely decline for your own sake. Global variables are allowed for a reason. Use them don’t be scared!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Class example, I fleshed out some basics, feel free to adapt to your needs.  The key here is all 'global' variables (nc, nr, and table) are simply stored as a Class Attribute to be accessed by Class Member Functions later (i.e. encrypt, decrypt).

```
import copy, sys

class MyApp(object):

    message = '''
        Choose:
        1. Build a table
        2. Encrypt
        3. Decrypt
        4. End
        '''

    opts = ['table', 'encrypt', 'decrypt', 'exit_']

    def __init__(self):

        self.at_menu = True
        self.main()

    def main(self):

        while self.at_menu:
            try:
                choice = raw_input(MyApp.message)
                # Executes the item in the list at the selected
                # option -1 (since python is base 0 by default)
                getattr(self, MyApp.opts[int(choice)-1])()

            except (KeyError, ValueError, IndexError):
                print 'Wrong choice'
            except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
                self.exit_

    def exit_(self):
        self.at_menu=False

    def table(self):

        self.nc = int(raw_input('Input number of columns: '))
        self.nr = int(raw_input('Input number of rows: '))

        row = [None for i in range(0,self.nc+1)]
        self.table = [copy.deepcopy(row) for i in range(0,self.nr+1)]
        for ch in range (1,self.nc+1):
            self.table[0][ch] = raw_input("Column Header {}: ".format(ch))

        for rh in range(1,self.nr+1):
            self.table[rh][0] = raw_input("Row Header {}: ".format(rh))

        for i in range(1,self.nr+1):
            for j in range(1,self.nc+1):
                self.table[i][j] = raw_input("Data {}{}: ".format(i,j))

        print str(self.table)

    def encrypt(self):

        #code using the class vars self.nc, self.nr, and etc
        pass

    def decrypt(self):

        #code using the class vars self.nc, self.nr, and etc
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp()
```